# Azure Network Security group

Tags: azure

I have a setup where database for my application is created in an VM is hosted inside a resource group. Now I am creating scaleset and vms in other resource groups(multiple stacks) all pointing to database VM. my problem is to create nsg rule to allow all those dynamically created VMs to access DB. I am creating rules dynamically now by creating rules with calculated priority. 
Is there is an easy way to do this?

Comment: are the other VM's located in the same virtual network?

Comment: Can we create a VIrtual Netwrok spanning multiple resource group??

Comment: As of now, no !!

Comment: You can have VM's from different resource groups in the same virtual network and NSG, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my problem is to create nsg rule to allow all those dynamically
>   created VMs to access DB.

If your VMSS(scaleset) and VM(database) use **the same Vnet**, maybe you can use internal IP address to communicate.

If your resource groups not use the same Vent and two resource groups **in the same region**, you can use [Vent peering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview) to connect them.

If your resource groups not use the same Vent and two resource groups **not in the same region**, maybe you can use site-to-site VPN to connect them(Vnet peering across Azure regions still in preview ).

Comment: Does that work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)